# IEEEtran cls and cleveref: the special case of IEEEeqnarray

Tags: ieeetran, cleveref

How to properly reference equations in an IEEEeqnarray with the cleveref package?

Here is possible MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,conference,twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.}
\crefname{figure}{fig.}{figs.}

\begin{document}
While referencing is not working for \Cref{Eq:not_working}, it is for \Cref{Eq:working}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  a &=& b\nonumber\\
  c &=& d
\label{Eq:not_working}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  a &=& b\\
  c &=& d
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\label{Eq:working}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply put: `IEEEtrantools.sty` uses `\stepcounter{equation}` instead of `\refstepcounter{equation}`, so `cleveref` can't guess what counter is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IEEEtrantools.sty` package uses `\stepcounter{equation}` and `\stepcounter{IEEEsubequation}` instead of `\refstepcounter`, so `cleveref` cannot guess what counter is involved.

Here's a patch that changes all `\stepcounter` commands to `\refstepcounter`. It has no influence on the macros of `IEEEtrantools`, because they set “manually” `\@currentlabel`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,conference,twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@IEEEyesnumber}
  {\stepcounter}
  {\refstepcounter}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@IEEEeqnarray}
  {\stepcounter}
  {\refstepcounter}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@IEEEeqnarraycr}
  {\stepcounter{IEEEsubequation}}
  {\refstepcounter{IEEEsubequation}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@IEEEeqnarraycr}
  {\stepcounter{IEEEsubequation}}
  {\refstepcounter{IEEEsubequation}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@IEEEeqnarraycr}
  {\stepcounter{IEEEequation}}
  {\refstepcounter{IEEEequation}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@IEEEeqnarraycr}
  {\stepcounter{IEEEequation}}
  {\refstepcounter{IEEEequation}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.}
\crefname{figure}{fig.}{figs.}


\begin{document}

While referencing is not working for \Cref{Eq:not_working}, 
it is for \cref{Eq:working}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  a &=& b\nonumber\\
  c &=& d
\label{Eq:not_working}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  a &=& b\\
  c &=& d
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\label{Eq:working}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Works perfectly!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you have a hunch as to why the `IEEEtran` document class and the `IEEEtrantools` package would use `\stepcounter` and change `\@currentlabel` "by hand" rather than use the `\refstepcounter` machinery?

Comment: @Mico I believe just because it sets `\@currentlabel` globally rather than locally as the LaTeX kernel does.